# Jboss Eap 7.x and maven

Tags: maven, ant, jboss-eap-7

Is maven really necessary for buidling application in jboss 7? I currently have an application which is running in jboss 5 and it is build by antbuild.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to manage application dependencies through maven. You just need to provide artifact details of jar and maven will take care of artifact and and its internal dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You will be happiest if you just adapt Maven.  You could try to manage dependencies yourself, but it will lead to many frustrations.

Use Maven, at least for JBoss.  Resistance is futile.